# Does "as long as" here mean the common known meaning of "as long as"?

Tags: phrase-meaning

[source](http://khnovel.com/this-is-falling/page-48-10039145.html)

> I want to stand here in this darkened hallway and have conversations
>   with her about absolutely nothing important for **as long as** it takes
>   for me to get enough balls to make a statement.

I know the meaning as in "as long as you're going, I'll go too". I don't sure "as long as" means that meaning. Maybe it means "it takes time as long as ... ".

Which part does "for" connect? "important for" or "for as long as"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

" as long as" here refers to the time.

> I want to stand here for 10 minutes, 20 minutes... or as long as it
>   takes ...

...

> for me to get enough courage to tell her something important (for me).

Answer (score 1):

"for as long as it takes" is the full phrase so is referring to time, which also answers the other part of your query. The whole sentence could be re-written as "I want to stand here chatting until I have worked up enough courage to declare my thoughts to her."